# How get the last update of Netbeans 7

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I currently use Netbeans 7.0.1. From the About Page : Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000). I use Netbeans under Ubuntu behind a proxy.

I see on Netbeans Website that a new version 7.1.2 is available http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html.

When I check for Update i saw : Your IDE is up to date! There are no updates available.

What is the problem ? I should download netbeans from the website and reinstall ?

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Just stumbled upon your question here, I hope there is a solution to auto-update Netbeans through the IDE.

Comment: @JurianSluiman Sadly No. I made the procedure of the answer.

Comment: why this question don't have 1543 upvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Netbeans 7.0.1 is not a simple "update", this is a new release. 
"Updates" are designed to update the current release, only. 
In addition, the "check for updates" button works very well - it shows updates and new releases.  You can download and install NB7.1.2 and import all the the NB7.0.1 preferences.

Comment: Is it the same form 7.1.1 to 7.1.2? I currently have 7.1.1 and the update window doesn't say anything about updates or the new version!